# Do difficulty or local difficulty affect spawn rates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Somewhere in [gnembon's Simple Hostile Mob Farms, Minecraft 1.12 (Fun Farms Ep. 15)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guvMmdeZqiI) video he mentions difficulty and local difficulty but I cannot remember where in the video.

In my 1.12 survival world I ran my build of his farm for an hour, getting about 4600 items/hr on Normal and about 6500 items/hr on Hard (regional difficulty 3.19, which is much lower than the max of 6.75). I ran the Normal test before the Hard test so the [local difficulty](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Difficulty#Regional_difficulty) may have changed slightly. Some of this effect might be due to [pack spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Pack_spawning) or just higher spawn rates.

The answers from [Advantages of hard mode in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37274/advantages-of-hard-mode-in-minecraft) are outdated.

I am looking for evidence based answers (tests, looking through game code), not hearsay or what the wiki says if it is unsourced.

Comment: The only relevant search result for "difficulty" on the "spawn" article is "the pack size can depend on difficulty" and the only relevant search result for "spawn" on the "difficulty" article is "Slimes are more likely to spawn in swamp biomes". So yes, a properly researched answer would be very good.

Comment: In regular gameplay it doesn't matter - regardless of difficulty mob cap is filled within seconds, and it is by far the main factor that regulates all new spawns. It will matter in case of efficient farms though, where mobs are killed or removed from cap otherwise fast enough that mob cap is not reached.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hostile mobs will spawn more when on hard mode than easy and normal mode.

Comment: What is your source for this

Comment: Its in the code, the Minecraft wiki and i did a test. Easy spawns around 1-3 mobs per chunk, normal spawns 3-6 and hard spawns 5-7 mobs per chunk

Comment: If it's in the code, show the relevant code snippet.

Comment: Its not a single line of code its part of a huge chunk of text

Comment: That's fine. I've posted code chunks in the past.

Comment: I will try to cut out relevant sections of code with it. To sum it up I believe that the difficulty increases pack sizes. I may be wrong but that is what i have understood.

Comment: Sorry for delay, i have been crammed with school work lately. I get back as soon as i can.

Comment: np. I believe it has to do with pack spawning too but I haven't looked through MCP code yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, spawn rates are not affected by difficulty.

However, there are effects of harder difficulty on spawned mobs, including (but not limited to):

- Chance of spawning with armor
- Chance of spawning with enchanted weapons
- Zombies and skeletons are more likely to pick up loot
- Slimes are more likely to be larger
- Spiders can spawn with speed, strength, regeneration or invisibility
- Zombies can spawn with reinforcements

I found these by searching for usages of the `getSpecialMultiplier` method in `net.minecraft.world.DifficultyInstance`.

I did not include any code snippets because you can't publish decompiled Minecraft code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure difficulty and local difficulty influences spawn rates since it was mentioned recently in ilmango's swamp slime farm video. Also sue me Mojang.